# How to `prompt` input and listen `keypress` in node js?

Tags: node.js

In my node application I want to listen keyboard `keypress` event.

So I did:

```
var readline = require('readline');

readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.on('keypress', keypress);

function keypress(_, key) {
   // ...
}
```

Some time I need to prompt user for additional input.
So...

```
var rl = readline.createInterface({ input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout });
rl.question("How Are You?\t", (Answer) => {
    // ...
    // after closeing `rl`, `keypress` function not called when any key pressed on keyboard.
    rl.close(); 
    // So, From now `keypress` not called anymore...Why? 
    setTimeout(() => console.log('Program end...'), 3 * 1000);  
});
```

So, I can listen keyboard `keypress` also `prompt` input...

The problem is after closing `rl`. How can i access `keypress` event ?

Pls help...

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you call `rl.close()`?

Comment: Nothing...I just want 'keypress' event active...even after closing readable stream...

Comment: Then you shouldn't close it. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: If I could...But is there any other way, without closing ?

Comment: Not really. Because of the way terminals work, you need to have *something* listening for keypresses. `readline` probably has to do some... stuff... to get the terminal to send it keypresses without doing any processing on its own.

Comment: Have you tried `readline.pause()` / `headline.resume()` between getting answers? I am not sure if that queues up the stream or not while in the paused state.